# I have already request lib but getting ImportError: No module named request

Tags: request

In Pip list Request lib is present but getting this issue .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
   import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request
```

Comment: I have tried but didn't get a solution.

Comment: If you look at the duplicate link above one of the answers states: *You cannot have request in Python 2, you need to have Python 3 or above.*